# Not getting any signal from myoware EMG muscle sensor. The signal LED (Red LED) on the sensor is always ON

Tags: arduino-mega

This is my first time using EMG Sensor.
I'm trying to read EMG signals from Myoware Muscle Sensor.
When I use analogRead to read analog value, the value is almost same. There is not much change in the analog value.

EMG Sensor I'm using: Myoware Muscle sensor from Advancer Technologies.
Arduino Board: Arduino Mega.

When Sensor is turned ON, the Signal LED (Red LED) on the emg sensor is always ON. (I don't know if it is supposed to be always ON or not )
I have tried placing emg sensor on both forearm and biceps, but no change in the analog value.
I really dont know what is wrong here.

This is the code:

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
}
 
void loop() {
  int sensorValue = analogRead(A5);
  //float millivolt = (sensorValue/1023)*5;
  
  Serial.print("Sensor Value: ");
  Serial.println(sensorValue);
  delay(1);       
}
```

[image: Circuit]

Comment: You are performing integer division in `(sensorValue/1023)*5`; this will result in 0 for any `sensorValue` less than `1023`.  It would help to know what values were coming out of `analogRead(A5)`

Comment: I am getting values in the range 676 to 680 at all time. I'm not using the milliVolt value. For now I just want to  get analog values depending on the muscle contraction.

Comment: Eventually, forcing to float, ... change to :  float millivolt = (sensorValue/1023.0 ) * 5.0 ; ?

Comment: Yes I will. But for that I have to get the correct analog reading first.

Comment: I see this board ... https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/myoware-muscle-sensor-kit/all but it is not the "same" ? I did not find your board.

Comment: Yes I'm using this board

Comment: Are you sure that the board in the picture above is "complete" ? It seems that it is only the MyoWare Cable board ? How did you wire the two boards ? https://cdn.sparkfun.com/assets/learn_tutorials/4/9/1/MyowareCable_ShieldStackedMuscleSensor.jpg ?

Comment: Sorry I missed to say that, When I designed the circuit in Fritzing, there was no myoware sensor board. Only cable board was available. So I choose it. Actually I'm using only the myoware sensor board.